# How to scroll related items in e-commerce website using php

Tags: php, mysql

Am creating a E-Commerce website using PHP. I have product page(product.php), in that page i need to scroll the related items based on categories. I did everything, but related items repeat two times(i mean one item comes two times but i want only once).

My code is following :

```
    // Class "item active"

<div class="item active">

    <?php
    $select = mysql_query("select * from product where categories ='$categories' limit 4");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
        $p_id = $rows['product_id'];
                          $p_img = $rows['image'];
                          $p_color = $rows['color'];
                          $p_name = $rows['product_name'];
                          $p_desc = $rows['product_detsils'];
                          $categories = $rows['categories'];
                          $p_offer = $rows['offer'];
                          $p_price = $rows['buying_price'];
    ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
             <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                   <div class="single-products">
                          <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                             <a href="product.php?product_id=<?php echo $p_id; ?>">
                <img src="images/product/<?php echo $p_img;?>.jpg" alt="" />
                <h2><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> <?php echo $p_price;?></h2>
                 <p><?php echo $p_name;?></p>
                                               </a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</button>
                           </div><!--productinfo text-center end-->
                     </div><!--single-products-->
                                 </div><!--product-image-wrapper end-->
                             </div><!--col-sm-3 end-->
    <?php } ?>

    </div><!--item active end-->




     //Classs "item"

    <div class="item ">

        <?php
        $select = mysql_query("select * from product where categories ='$categories' limit 4");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($select))
        {
            $p_id = $rows['product_id'];
                              $p_img = $rows['image'];
                              $p_color = $rows['color'];
                              $p_name = $rows['product_name'];
                              $p_desc = $rows['product_detsils'];
                              $categories = $rows['categories'];
                              $p_offer = $rows['offer'];
                              $p_price = $rows['buying_price'];
        ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                       <div class="single-products">
                              <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                                 <a href="product.php?product_id=<?php echo $p_id; ?>">
                    <img src="images/product/<?php echo $p_img;?>.jpg" alt="" />
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> <?php echo $p_price;?></h2>
                     <p><?php echo $p_name;?></p>
                                                   </a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</button>
                               </div><!--productinfo text-center end-->
                         </div><!--single-products-->
                                     </div><!--product-image-wrapper end-->
                                 </div><!--col-sm-3 end-->
        <?php } ?>

        </div><!--item end-->
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Thanks for replaying, what i want to use ? @Smuuf

Comment: mysqli_* or PDO. Because in nearly years mysql_* won't work anymore..

Comment: Are you sure products are not doubled in database? What is the HTML output from that piece of code?

Comment: Also - escape strings coming from external sources (eg. database) properly. Use `<?php echo htmlentities($p_name);?>` instead of `<?php echo $p_name;?>`. You can't possibly always know what product names will be put it and where will they come from. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection

Comment: i updated only once@caCtus

Comment: I hadn't seen the whole code. You are querying the database twice with the same query and displaying items twice. Remove one of these, or describe what you are trying to do and why you are doing it twice.

Comment: i did class **item activate** but i want only **item**. Just a look my code @caCtus

Comment: Remove `item activate` part if you don't want it. Or be more precise about why you can't remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing same query twice that's why you product listed twice use only one like:

```
<div class="item active">

    <?php
    $select = mysql_query("select * from product where categories ='$categories' limit 4");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
        $p_id = $rows['product_id'];
                          $p_img = $rows['image'];
                          $p_color = $rows['color'];
                          $p_name = $rows['product_name'];
                          $p_desc = $rows['product_detsils'];
                          $categories = $rows['categories'];
                          $p_offer = $rows['offer'];
                          $p_price = $rows['buying_price'];
    ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
             <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                   <div class="single-products">
                          <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                             <a href="product.php?product_id=<?php echo $p_id; ?>">
                <img src="images/product/<?php echo $p_img;?>.jpg" alt="" />
                <h2><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> <?php echo $p_price;?></h2>
                 <p><?php echo $p_name;?></p>
                                               </a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</button>
                           </div><!--productinfo text-center end-->
                     </div><!--single-products-->
                                 </div><!--product-image-wrapper end-->
                             </div><!--col-sm-3 end-->
    <?php } ?>

    </div><!--item active end-->
```

and as look like you trying to wind in two div with two different class then first you need to identified what point you need to segregate.